# auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

**base.jsx**:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


const firebaseConfig = {
config
  };

  export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  export const auth = getAuth();
```

**Register.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "../components/base";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Register() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleRegister = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="register">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="box">
          <form onSubmit={handleRegister}>
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control"
                id="email"
                placeholder="Enter email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                id="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Register
            </button>
            <div>{error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}</div>
          </form>
          <p className="sign-up">
            Already have an account?
            <Link to="/login">
              <span>Login</span>
            </Link>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9M9L.png)

It's pretty much self explanatory, can you guys please help me fix this issue? I've been struggling for 2 hours.

I want createUserWithEmailAndPassword to work in Register.jsx so I can later on sign in Login.jsx with the same information. However on the website when I click the submit button in Register.jsx, *auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function* pops out

Answer (score 1):

You're using the v9 SDK version, which uses a modular API with top-level functions. So `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is not longer a method on the `auth` object, but is now a top-level function that you have to import similar to what you do for `getAuth` and to which you then pass the `auth` object as its first parameter:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "username", "password")
```

When you are programming this new API or getting errors otherwise, I recommend keeping the documentation handy. In this case you can see code similar to what you're trying and what I have above in the documentation on [creating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account). Also have a look at the blog post [introducing the modular SDK](https://firebase.blog/posts/2021/07/introducing-the-new-firebase-js-sdk), and the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).